# How to monitor total outgoing bandwidth usage on a per-user basis?

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, bandwidth, usage

How does one monitor total outgoing bandwidth usage on a per-user basis?

(I'm using apache 2.2 in case you need this information.)

All web hosts do this.  So it would seem obvious, but I can't find any information on how to do this.  Even a partial answer would help.

Remember, I don't care about the user's rate of usage, only their total bandwidth usage.

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: What's a "user" in the context of your question? Like, say, "Evan Anderson" on "ServerFault.com", or, like "ServerFault.com" on a shared hosting provider?

Comment: I strongly disagree with the statement that "all web hosts do this".

Comment: @Evan Anderson - Both! Monitoring users on a website in limited contexts might be useful.  My original question is regarding a site on a shared hosting provider.

@womble - Every web host I've come across limits your total monthly bandwidth usage.  I just figured that they do this by monitoring you somehow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the logs with a custom script.  You'll also likely want a custom log format (to capture the VirtualHost names.)  You can either parse the logs daily (or hourly/weekly) or you can run the logs through a script as it happens.

```
LogFormat "%B \"%{Host}i\"" myformat
CustomLog "|/usr/local/bin/apachebwmeter" myformat
```

It's up to you to write /usr/local/bin/apachebwmeter.  Make sure to coalesce the domain names (www.example.com and example.com are the same user, you might have other variations depending on your environment.)  Keep in mind that %B does NOT include HTTP headers, so it'll be approximate.

-Dave

Answer (score 1):

> All web hosts do this.

It's my observation that most web hosts *don't* do this. Most that I've seen record a copy of the logfiles in a (root-owned) directory and check them monthly.

[We](http://www.internetconnection.net/) used [ipfm](http://robert.cheramy.net/ipfm/), but now we use [ipa](http://gpl.internetconnection.net/files/ipa.tar.gz).

> Remember, I don't care about the user's rate of usage, only their total bandwidth usage.

When you buy rate of usage, translating it into cost is dependent on your utilization *in addition to your usage*.

For example, if you buy a $3000/month DS3, and you're at 85% utilization, your cost is $3000 for 94.55T or about 32$/T, but if you're only at 50% utilization, that's $3000 for 55.61T or about 54$/T.